# Visible image edges on carousel with rounded borders

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've implemented a bootstrap carousel in the header of a webpage. The header has a border-radius of 30px on the top left and top right corner. Whenever a new image rolls in, the edges of the image, which also have a border-radius, become visible. Once the carousel stops, the edges go back to rounded like it's defined in the CSS. Is there any way to fix this? I've already tried "overflow:hidden" on the "img"-tag and the header itself with no luck.

Please take a look at my screenshot.
[carousel when image rolls in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1vSi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: try adding.. border-left-radius:5px; on image

Comment: for image tag try `border-radius: 30px;`

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't help